# How to access a controller function in directives with isolated scope?

Tags: angularjs

I have a function in my controller name as **enableEditor** it is working if i call the function from direct HTML i.e(add). But, if I call the function for a element which is created through the directives i.e(edit) is not working. Please look at my code and advice me if any ideas.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example53-production</title>
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div user-name=""></div>
  <div>
  <a href="#" ng-click="enableEditor()">add</a>
  </div>
<script>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

 myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$filter', function ($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.enableEditor = function() {
        alert("123");
    };  
}]);
myApp.directive("userName", function() {
    return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope: {
                value: "=userName"
            },
            template: '<div class="click-to-edit">' +
            '<a href="#" ng-click="enableEditor()">Edit</a>' +
            '</div>'
        };
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have an isolated scope the function belongs to the scope of the directive not your controller. Try using `&` in your directives scope like this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div user-name="" callme="enableEditor()"></div>
  <div>
  <a href="#" ng-click="enableEditor()">add</a>
  </div>
<script>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

 myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$filter', function ($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.enableEditor = function() {
        alert("123");
    };  
}]);
myApp.directive("userName", function() {
    return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope: {
                value: "=userName",
                callme:"&"
            },
            template: '<div class="click-to-edit">' +
            '<a href="#" ng-click="callme()">Edit</a>' +
            '</div>'
        };
});
```

The attribute `callme="enableEditor()"` is used to pass the method to the scope directive, the directive scope uses `&` to indicate it is method `callme:"&"`.  Another example:

`method2="someMethod()"` like

```
scope: {
      value: "=userName",
      callme:"&",    
      method2:"&"
},template: '<div class="click-to-edit">' + '<a href="#" ng-click="callme()">Edit</a>' + '<a href="#" ng-click="Method2()">Save</a>' + '</div>'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response. It is working for me if create one function in the template. If I need to create 2 function links on the template then how I need to call this.

template: '<div class="click-to-edit">' +
            '<a href="#" ng-click="callme()">Edit</a>' +
   '<a href="#" ng-click="save()">Save</a>' +
   '</div>'

Comment: @user3621148 I added the sample. Hopefully that will explains it. Please do not forget to mark this as your answer if it helps you.